# Not All Files Appearing In Git Clone

Tags: git, github, clone, githooks, ruby-overcommit

All I am trying to do is clone a Git Hook Manager called Git Overcommit. But when I open the file from my desktop, some of the files that I need to be working with are not there for some reason (or I just cannot find them). I am assuming (hoping) it's something small that I am missing here, specifically I cannot find the `.overcommit.yml` and `.git-hooks/pre_commit` files.

Here are some screenshots to clarify. The first picture is of all the files I am cloning (all the files I could fit in the screenshot). And the second is of the files that I actually have on my desktop after I clone it. You'll notice many of the `.yml` ones are missing.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [dotfiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments), which are hidden by default. You [can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/186378) to see them in Finder.

Answer (score 1):

It's because files that starts with "." are hidden :)

https://www.lifewire.com/display-hidden-files-in-os-x-153332